# Jquery error method not displaying desired result

Tags: jquery

```
<img src="one.jpg" height="200" width="200">            
<img src="three.jpg" height="200" width="200"><br>      

<a href="mylink.html"><u> Click Here  </u></a><br>      

<script src="displayAlert.js"></script>             

<style type="text/css" src="externCSS.css"> </style> 


$(document).ready(function(){
   $("[src]").error(function(){
        alert ("error");
      });
});
```

Expected Output - The code should display the alert when the files are not present at the specified path.

The jquery is displaying the alert only when the image files are not present at the specified path. It is not displaying anything for css or script files if they are not present. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: instead of src use img as selector.

Comment: but I want to check errors for elements which have src attribute defined not only images.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761708/what-browsers-fully-support-script-tag-onerror-and-when-is-it-fired

Comment: $("*").error(...) doesn't fire on error file missing (just 2 img miss), so, i don't think u can handle it like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("img")
.error(function(){
$(this).hide();
})
.attr("src", "missing.png");
```

To check if attr is defined for `DOM` use.

```
var attr = $(this).attr('src');
// `attr` is false.  Check for both.
if (typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false) {
    //code goes here
}
```

**Pass Multiple selector**

```
$(window).load(function()
{
    $('script,img,link').each(function()
    {
        var attr = $(this).attr('src');
        // `attr` is false.  Check for both.
        if (typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false)
        {
            //code goes here
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is only for image I want to find it for all external resources such as external javascript file. I want to find which external resources are failing to load not only image. All external resources which fail to load should give me an error

Comment: @Neeraj  so pass img script link etc as selector...i mean pass multiple selector

Comment: alerts me five times i.e once for each resource or script, img, link

Comment: @Neeraj is it wrong.?? BTW anchor link don't have src attribute...also your style tag must be link tag with href

Comment: I want to display error only when an external resource such as js file, image, css fails to load, so in the above code my js file is not on the specified path but image paths are correct so it should give me an error only for js file

Comment: You are missleading @Neeraj, your code does not provide solution to the problem. the code just checks for valid 'src' attrubute. He wants to trigger handler on error. The code I have posted below could be solution. It is also tested.

Comment: @Boynux i am not missleading him i just trying to help him...but i think we both don't understand each other..

Comment: I understand you are trying to help him, Thank you and I appriciate that, but you must put him in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is what written in jQuery [jQuery error](http://api.jquery.com/error/)

> The event handler **must be attached before the browser fires the error
>   event, which is why the example sets the src attribute after attaching
>   the handler.** Also, the error event may not be correctly fired when the
>   page is served locally; error relies on HTTP status codes and will
>   generally not be triggered if the URL uses the file: protocol.

It means you must attach handler before page load complete.
This is your problem I think.

and this is jQuery sample code:

```
$('#book')
    .error(function() {
    alert('Handler for .error() called.')
}).attr("src", "missing.png");
```

if you are looking for a ready to use solution i suggest this:

```
<img url="one.jpg" height="200" width="200"> 
<img url="three.jpg" height="200" width="200"><br>

<a href="mylink.html"><u> Click Here  </u></a><br>

<script url="displayAlert.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css" url="externCSS.css"> </style>

<script>
   $("[url]").each ( function () {
        $(this).error (function () {
            alert ( "Error" );
        }).attr ( 'src',  $(this).attr ("url"));
    });
</script>
```